# console.error: "Unhandled error" Network error: Network request failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm getting an error red screen like this in my react native application.

[image]

This error occurs when I disable internet conection in the device (real device or simulator), or any kind of server error ocurrs.

I'm following next documentation info to "handle" errors with apollo and react native:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-query-data-error

In my code has something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    ActivityIndicator,
    View,
    FlatList,
    TouchableHighlight,
    TextInput,
    Button,
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo';
import ZONES_QUERY from '../graphql/zones.query'


class ZonesScreen extends Component {


    render() {
        const { zones, loading, error } = this.props;


        if (loading) {
            return (
                <ActivityIndicator style={styles.activityIndicator} size='large' />
            )
        } else if (error) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>Unexcpeted Error</Text>
                    <Button title="retry" onPress={() => { this.props.refetch() }}></Button>

                </View>

            )
        } else {
            return (
                <View
                    style={styles.container}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={zones}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => ZoneRenderItem(item)}
                        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}

                    />
                </View>
            )
        }
    }

    //HELPER FUNCTIONS

    keyExtractor = item => item._id;
}

ZonesScreen.propTypes = {
    refetch: PropTypes.func,
}


const zonesQuery = graphql(ZONES_QUERY, {
    options: {
        forceFetch: true,
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    },
    props: ({ data: { loading, getRoutes, error, refetch } }) => ({
        loading,
        zones: getRoutes,
        refetch,
        error,
    }),
})



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
    },
    activityIndicator: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

export default compose(
    zonesQuery,
)(ZonesScreen)
```

my client configuration with apollo has something like this:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError}) => {
    console.log("ERROR: " +networkError)    
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: concat(errorLink, httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

I have two screens.

Screen A: it does contain a button to go screen B.
Screen B: contains a list of zones (this information is fetch from server).

the steps to reproduce this error are the next ones:

1. - I open the app. (I see screen A). I disable internet conection from device, I tap button to go screen B.
2. Screen B is shown with an error message. This is handled in my code in the line:

   else if (error) {}

this is the expected behaviour, but when I go back to screen A by pressing back button in Navbar / Toolbar. THE RED SCREEN IS SHOWN.

I don't know what I'm missing,

any help is good, thanks in advance.

I am using

"react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.27"

"react-apollo": "2.0.4",